# c++,boost::spirit parse the text

Tags: c++, boost, grammar, boost-spirit

everyone!

I want to use boost::spirit to parse some string in text file.

Here is the sample in the text file:

```
IF([banana] and [apple] and [yellow] or [green] or [red] and [!white])

THEN

do sth...;

ELSE

do  sth...;
```

When i parse the string in the "if" bracket i got a trouble.

Here is my code:

```
if_rule=str_p(IF)>>ch_p("(")>>if_mem>>*("and"|"or">>if_mem)>>ch_p(")");

if_mem=ch_p("[")>>*~ch_p("]")>>ch_p("]");
```

It dose not work.It just parse the two "and" of the beginning and ignore the "or".

I've try several different grammer and still didn't work.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @jv_ Thank you!In boost::spirit,bitwise "or" means logical "or".May create some bitmaps to check the grammar occurs or not.

Comment: `("and"|"or")` couldn't compile.And i've got new trouble.   `ruleA=!ruleB&&!ruleC`,how could i express it in boost::spirit

Comment: You seem to be using the obsolete "classical" Spirit. Consider updating to Spirit v2 (it's a decade old).

Comment: @sehe How could i bind a member function to a parsed string?Or pass a class instance to the parse grammar struct.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that ultimately a Spirit expression is simply a (really ugly) c++ expression and thus it must follow c++ rules. Independently of the meaning that Spirit gives to the operators, they still follow [c++ operator precedence rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). And so the expression `"and" | "or" >> if_mem` is not the same as (`"and"` or `"or"`) followed by `if_mem` but in fact is `"and"` or (`"or"` followed by `if_mem`) since `>>` has a higher precedence than `|`. If you use `("and"|"or")>>if_mem` you face another separate problem: since none of its arguments is a Spirit expression, the operator `|` is not the alternative parser, but the default c++ bitwise_or operator and that, as you discovered, causes a compiler error. The solution in this case is to make at least one of the arguments a Spirit expression by using (I'm just guessing since I don't use Spirit.Classic) something like `(str_p("and")|str_p("or"))>>if_mem`. (I guess `"and">>if_mem | "or">>if_mem` should also work, but it's probably a worse alternative).

As sehe points in his comment, if you have a choice (unless you need to work with legacy code basically) you should probably use Spirit v2 since it will be far easier to get help.